# Can't verify signature ECDSA key

Tags: javascript, cryptography, java-7, public-key-encryption, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to create a key pair with ECDSA algorithm using javascript, sign a message and then verify it server-side (with Java).

sample javascript code:

```js
    // help function
    function _arrayBufferToBase64( buffer ) {
        var binary = '';
        var bytes = new Uint8Array( buffer );
        var len = bytes.byteLength;
        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            binary += String.fromCharCode( bytes[ i ] );
        }
        return window.btoa( binary );
    }
    const encodedMessage = new TextEncoder().encode('test');

    // keys generation
    crypto.subtle.generateKey({
        name: 'ECDSA',
        namedCurve: 'P-256'
    }, true, ['sign','verify']).then((keys) => {

        console.log('keys:', keys);
        console.log('[....] public key export');

        // public key export
        crypto.subtle.exportKey('spki', keys.publicKey).then(result => {

            console.log('publicKey byte:', result);
            console.log('publicKey base64:', _arrayBufferToBase64(result));
  
            // sign
            crypto.subtle.sign({
                    name: 'ECDSA',
                    hash: {name:'SHA-256'}
                },
                keys.privateKey,
                encodedMessage
                ).then(signature => {

                    console.log('signature byte:', signature);
                    console.log('signature base64:', _arrayBufferToBase64(signature));
          
                    // verify
                    crypto.subtle.verify({
                            name: 'ECDSA',
                            hash: {name: 'SHA-256'}
                        },
                        keys.publicKey,
                        signature,
                        encodedMessage
                    ).then(verified => {
                         console.log('signature verified?', verified);
                    });
                });
         });
     });
```

For example:

```
    publicKey base64: MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAERhn3GM1eQodijVDdy0Zb+ERjvWZ6idQw8PbaFfTzPdA7oNFh8+AHlni91snTS5Sk2o4Xw9CCnlvHP3uWVyCIvA==
    signature base64: nAHPhibM3txezQ53O3C4vMlbQnMI75ILcaamqBezNS51c6wB2ZHwwk/4phgbp+aFlM9omvxaH0fdzJpCT0s/Zg==
    signature verified? true
```

and everything is fine.

The problem is I can't verify the same message both using Java or [this website](https://8gwifi.org/ecsignverify.jsp):

[image]

Java code:

```
private boolean receiver(String message, String algorithm, String signature, String publicKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException, UnsupportedEncodingException, SignatureException {

    Signature ecdsaVerify = Signature.getInstance(algorithm);

    //import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
    byte[] decodedPk = Base64.decodeBase64(new String(publicKey).getBytes("UTF-8"));
    EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(decodedPk);

    KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");
    PublicKey pk = keyFactory.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);
    
    ecdsaVerify.initVerify(pk);
    
    byte[] decodedString = new String(message).getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] decodedSignature = Base64.decodeBase64(new String(signature).getBytes("UTF-8"));

    ecdsaVerify.update(decodedString);
    boolean result = ecdsaVerify.verify(decodedSignature);

    return result;
}
```

Where

```
    String message = "test";
    String algorithm = "SHA256withECDSA";
    String signature = "nAHPhibM3txezQ53O3C4vMlbQnMI75ILcaamqBezNS51c6wB2ZHwwk/4phgbp+aFlM9omvxaH0fdzJpCT0s/Zg==";
    String publicKey = "MFkwEwYHKoZIzj0CAQYIKoZIzj0DAQcDQgAERhn3GM1eQodijVDdy0Zb+ERjvWZ6idQw8PbaFfTzPdA7oNFh8+AHlni91snTS5Sk2o4Xw9CCnlvHP3uWVyCIvA==";
```

And I got this exception:

```
    [err] java.security.SignatureException: Could not verify signature
    [err]   at sun.security.ec.ECDSASignature.engineVerify(ECDSASignature.java:325)
    [err]   at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1223)
    [err]   at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:656)
    [err]   at it.bpc.bpwebrs.application.services.IamService.receiver(IamService.java:2740)
    [err]   at it.bpc.bpwebrs.application.services.IamService.elaboraAbilitazioni(IamService.java:186)
    [err]   at it.bpc.bpwebrs.infrastructure.servicesImpl.IamResource.eseguiServizioElaborazione(IamResource.java:127)
    [err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    [err]   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    [err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    [err]   at it.bpc.bpwebrs.dispatcher.DispatcherResource.richiamaServizioRichiesto(DispatcherResource.java:447)
    [err]   at it.bpc.bpwebrs.dispatcher.DispatcherResource.postJSONRequest(DispatcherResource.java:227)
    [err]   at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor77.invoke(Unknown Source)
    [err]   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    [err]   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory$1.invoke(ResourceMethodInvocationHandlerFactory.java:81)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher$1.run(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:144)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.invoke(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:161)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider$ResponseOutInvoker.doDispatch(JavaResourceMethodDispatcherProvider.java:160)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.internal.AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.dispatch(AbstractJavaResourceMethodDispatcher.java:99)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.invoke(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:389)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:347)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ResourceMethodInvoker.apply(ResourceMethodInvoker.java:102)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:326)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
    [err]   at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
    [err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1285)
    [err]   at [internal classes]
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:155)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(OAuth2AuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:176)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:50)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
    [err]   at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    [err]   at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    [err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    [err]   at [internal classes]
    [err]   at it.bpc.bpwebrs.infrastructure.security.cors.CorsFilter.doFilter(CorsFilter.java:180)
    [err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    [err]   at [internal classes]
    [err]   at it.bpc.bpwebrs.infrastructure.filters.MDCFilter.doFilter(MDCFilter.java:49)
    [err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    [err]   at [internal classes]
    [err]   at it.bpc.bpwebrs.utilities.infrastructure.EncodingFilter.doFilter(EncodingFilter.java:30)
    [err]   at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    [err]   at [internal classes]
    [err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    [err]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    [err]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    [err] Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Invalid encoding for signature
    [err]   at sun.security.ec.ECDSASignature.decodeSignature(ECDSASignature.java:400)
    [err]   at sun.security.ec.ECDSASignature.engineVerify(ECDSASignature.java:322)
    [err]   ... 92 more
    [err] Caused by: java.io.IOException: Sequence tag error
    [err]   at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getSequence(DerInputStream.java:330)
    [err]   at sun.security.ec.ECDSASignature.decodeSignature(ECDSASignature.java:376)
    [err]   

... 93 more
```

What am'I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different formats for an ECDSA signature, on the one hand the IEEE P1363 (r|s) format, on the other hand ASN.1/DER encoded.

The relationship between the two formats is explained [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/57731).

WebCrypto applies the IEEE P1363 format, the website and the `SHA256withECDSA` algorithm in the Java code use ASN.1/DER, which is the reason for the issue.

The SunEC provider also supports IEEE P1363, for this the algorithm to be applied is `SHA256withECDSAinP1363Format`. With this the verification works with the Java code.

**Edit:**

Alternatively, BouncyCastle can be used, which supports both formats:

```java
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;
...
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
Signature ecdsaVerify = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withPlain-ECDSA", "BC"); //IEEE P1363
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried ``SHA256withECDSAinP1363Format`` but it's only available with Java 9 (I'm stucked at Java 7...). I think I shloud convert javascript signature to ASN.1 format then...

Comment: @ErnestoSchiavo - This is one possibility, although WebCrypto as a low-level crypto library does not support this format conversion. Another, probably easier, way is to use BouncyCastle in the Java code, which supports both formats.

Comment: @ErnestoSchiavo - Added the BC alternative.